# Does ie support first-child and last-child?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-6

Does any body know `first-child` and `last-child` support old IE like IE6 and IE7.

I think when using jQuery it works, is that right ?

is it problem with CSS only ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html :

`first-child`: IE6: No.  IE7/8: Yes with caveats.  IE9+: yes.

`last-child`: IE6/7/8: No. IE9+: Yes.

jQuery supports them everywhere.